# Pass data from CollectionviewCell to ViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

when i write the function touchphoto, the post.postID is nil .I want to pass the postID to another view controller. I add the code for the profilecell and profileviewcontroller

```
protocol profilecellDelegate {
func goToPhotoDetail(postid: String)}

class profilecell: UICollectionViewCell {
var delegate: profilecellDelegate?

@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

var post: Post? {
    didSet {
        updateView()
    }
}

func updateView() {
    if let photoUrlString = post?.photoUrl {
        let photoUrl = URL(string: photoUrlString)
        image.sd_setImage(with: photoUrl)
    }
}

@IBAction func touchphoto(_ sender: Any) {
    if let id = post?.postID {
        delegate?.goToPhotoDetail(postid: id)
    }
}
}



//profileviewcontroller
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "profilecell", for: indexPath) as! profilecell
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.post = post
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
extension ProfileViewController: profilecellDelegate {
func goToPhotoDetail(postid: String) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Photo_ProfileSegue", sender: postid)
}}
```

Comment: Is post also nil? Where do you set the postID?

Comment: in the profileviewcontroller when i add the function fetchprofile

Comment: Please share that code as well.

Comment: ok thank you,resolved

Comment: What was the solution, please share for future readers.